# как лучше записать работу с двумя векторами, один из которых является постоянной частью другого

Tags: c++

Исходное моё предположение исподьзовать `union` оказалось ошибочным.
Тот вопрос удалил, переформулирую заново ближе к задаче.

Суть задачи такова, что есть вектор постоянного количества частиц `std::vector<int> core`, и есть добавочная к нему часть временно порождаемых частиц на каждом цикле. Весь набор частиц вместе с порождаемыми хранится в `std::vector<int> extended`. Вектор `core` создаётся в начале программы, а порождаемая часть создаётся в начале каждого цикла `extended.resize(total_number_particles)`, и в конце забывается `extended.resize(core_number_particles)`.

При этом удобно использовать для обхода по векторам `for (auto elem : core) { ... }` и `for (auto elem : extended)`.

Как всё это лучше представить в программе?
Пока предположение такое: создать

```
struct Particles {
  std::vector<int> core;
  std::vector<int> extended;
}
```

И в `main`:

```
int main() {
  Particles particles;
  int core_number = 10;
  particle.core.resize(core_number);
  particle.core.pushback( ... ) // заполнение `core`
  // цикл:
    &particles.extended = &particles.core; // адрес второго вектора равен адресу первого
    int extended_number = core_number * 10;
    particles.extended.resize(extended_number);
    particles.extended = particles.core; // копирование первых core_number элементов
    particles.extended.pushback( ... ); // заполнение элементов [core_number, extended_number)
    // ... внутренности цикла
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например хранить размер основного вектора и работать с одним вектором:

```
struct Particles { 
    const size_t core_size;
    std::vector<int> extended;
    Particles(const std::vector<int>& core) 
        : core_size(core.size()), extended(core) {}
};
void foo()
    Particles v({ 2, 4, 5 });
    v.extended.resize(10);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.core_size; ++i)
        //...
}
```

Или же хранить  вектор двух векторов:

```
enum {core, extended};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(2);
```

И использовать `vec[core]` и `vec[extended]`, добавляя только во второй вектор.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
  В первом вашем способе `for (auto elem : v.extended)` верно, а `for (auto elem : core)` - нет, вместо него ваш `for (size_t i = 0; i < v.core_size; ++i)`
  Во втором вашем способе vec[extended] - это только временные частицы, или все вообще (лишняя трата памяти повторением core два раза)?
  Задача была использовать удобный `range-for` и для `core`, и для полного `extended`, при этом не повторяя частицы из `core` в памяти два раза.

Comment: Почему-то разрывы строки не вставляются, поэтому весь текст подряд получается.

Comment: Во втором способе просто не нужно содержимое первого вектора копировать во второй, а первый способ вы можете модифицировать под ваши нужды. Это только вам знать чего вам нужно.  Я же ответил на вопрос  "как можно работать с двумя векторами, один из которых является постоянной частью другого". Это можно делать десятками способами, вы сами должны выбирать какой способ лучше вам подойдет,